ListView of NumberBox with minimum constraint corrupts value when ordered
Consider this minimal example;
xaml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Window
    x:Class="NumberboxText.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:NumberboxText"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="NumberboxText"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Sort</Button>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TestItem">
                    <NumberBox
                    Value="{x:Bind Current, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Minimum="{x:Bind Min}"
                />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Media.Capture.Frames;

namespace NumberboxText;

public class TestItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _order;
    private int _min;
    private int _current;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    public int Order
    {
        get => _order;
        set => SetProperty(ref _order, value);
    }

    public int Min
    {
        get => _min;
        set => SetProperty(ref _min, value);
    }

    public int Current
    {
        get => _current;
        set => SetProperty(ref _current, value);
    }

    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        field = value;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public readonly ObservableCollection<TestItem> Items = [];
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Items.Add(new TestItem { Order = 3, Min = 3, Current = 3 });
        Items.Add(new TestItem { Order = 1, Min = 1, Current = 1 });
        Items.Add(new TestItem { Order = 4, Min = 4, Current = 4 });
        Items.Add(new TestItem { Order = 2, Min = 2, Current = 2 });

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (var i = Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                if (Items[j - 1].Order > Items[j].Order)
                {
                    Items.Move(j - 1, j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


When I click the sort button, I am getting this;

It looks like listview tries to change numberbox values in place, but it can't because of Minimum constraint, causing the change on values.
Should I consider this a bug to report, or is there a way I can make this work?

Instead of moving items in the ObservableCollection, you could create a new sorted list and replace the existing items in the ObservableCollection. This would prevent the ListView from trying to update the NumberBox values in place.

@Mellik Problem persists thay way, it probably re-uses underlying controls.

You could create a small wrapper class which takes the item itself and the value and then fill a list of that wrapper class and then sort that. Then clear the original Items list and add the list to it

This behavior seems to be based on the order of the XAML code.
In the case below, Minimum is set after Value:
<NumberBox
    Value="{x:Bind Current, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Minimum="{x:Bind Min}" />

Changing the order seems to fix you issue:
<NumberBox
    Minimum="{x:Bind Min}"
    Value="{x:Bind Current, Mode=TwoWay}" />

Note that changing the order on Items, doesn't mean that the ListView will change its ListViewItems accordingly. The ListView might reuse its available ListViewItems, which might have the Minimum set from its previous item, and bind the corresponding item.

Thanks for the answer! For now, I have decided to move input boxes out of ListView. I have created an edit form that bind to SelectedItem property of ListView. I don't want to depend on order of properties because they can be unintentionally reordered by formatters, or new versions of xaml compiler might decide to do things differently, therefore changing behaviour without notice.

Also posted a bug report here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/10182
